# Application based on Gstreamer + Gtk+3 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gtk, gstreamer, gtk3, ubuntu-18.04, gtkbuilder

What is the good and efficient language to develop a video streaming application using **Gstreamer + gtk+** ??

The application which we developed has to do things notify the user whenever the some uneven behaviour occured where we are looking into...

Any suggestions will be useful.....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Of course depends on your liking and what else you need and want to do in the application. Since you are Gtk and Linux I would recommend to look at Vala:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala

I made a proof of concept app with that at some time to watch Twitch.tv streams:

https://github.com/fzwoch/twit-twat

Maybe take a look if you are fine with the ease and look of the language for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

No troll intended, but Vala looks like a dead end for most people I talk to. It's a specific language that never caught outside of GNOME, and I'm not sure it has the brightest future.

Rust seems to get wider adoption but seems still at an early age, still usable though, even for GStreamer use.

Python is both adopted, simple, and has stable bindings.

If you prefer a compiled language, C++ and GTKmm would be a possibility too, but at this point, depending on your requirements, and assuming you're not afraid of the moving ecosystem, Rust might still be a better choice.